# How to get exact textContent of XPATH using Puppeteer.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

node.js / javascript using puppeteer.js

I'm trying to get the exact text of an xpath using puppeteer, but it's just returning the content as one string. A sample of the HTML content of the xpath here:

```
<div class="footNote" style="display: block;">
<br>
<strong>Note 17</strong>
<br>
34 people attended this event.
</div>
```

The code I'm using to scrape the text of the xpath:

```
var xPath = `//*[@id="contentWrapper"]/div[${xNum}]/div[${yNum}]/div`
[qr] = await page.$x(xPath);
txt = await qr.getProperty('textContent');
const textContent = await txt.jsonValue();
console.log(textContent)
```

The problem is, the string textContent returns is "Note 1734 people attended this event."

I need to be able to get these two strings separately and not mashed together as one string. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by using

```
qr.getProperty('innerHTML')
```

then using RegEx to strip away HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

If you need readable text, try `qr.getProperty('innerText');` instead of `qr.getProperty('textContent');`.

See [`HTMLElement.innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText).

Comment: I still get the same output from changing "textContent" to "innerText"..

Comment: Can you provide the URL? The sample in your question cannot produce the "Note 1734 people attended this event." string (it has literal line breaks), so it is hard to suggest what can be wrong.

Comment: I fixed this problem by instead using innerHTML then using regex to remove the HTML tags. using innerText and textContent gave me the same exact results.

Comment: There is a slight chance when they can be the same: when the elements present in the DOM but are not rendered (via CSS hiding, for example), then innerText fall back to textContent. Maybe this is your case. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by instead using innerHTML and using regex to remove the HTML tags. I was getting the same results using both innerText and textContent